# What is the inverse of $f(x)=x^{x^x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, arithmetic-functions

I'm curious to find the inverse of $ f(x)=x^{x^x} $

As an added extra, I'm already familiar with the Lambert Product Log function.

Comment: WA says that it can't find an inverse in terms of standard mathematical functions. You know that one exists since $f'$ can be shown to be positive. And if WA is correct, then the best you can do is make up your own name for the inverse of this $f$.

Comment: See [*super roots* or *super radicals*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Inverse_relations).